# Does finitely generated associated graded module imply stable filtration?

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring and $\mathfrak a$ be an ideal of $R$. Then

(i) $G_{\mathfrak a}(R)$ is Noetherian.

(ii) If $M$ is a finitely generated $R$-module and $\mathcal F=\{M_n\}$ is a stable $\mathfrak a$-filtration, then $G_{\mathcal F}(M)$ is a finitely generated $G_{\mathfrak a}(R)$-module.

But what is the converse of (ii), i.e., if $G_{\mathcal F}(M)$ is a finitely generated $G_{\mathfrak a}(R)$-module does that imply the filtration is stable?

I think if $\mathfrak a =\operatorname{Ann}(M)$ this gives a counter example to the converse.

Comment: Please show why do you think that $G_{\mathcal F}(M)$ is a finitely generated $G_{\mathfrak a}(R)$-module when $\mathfrak a =\operatorname{Ann}(M)$.

Comment: @YACP, thanks for the reply, I take $R = \mathbb Z$ and $ I = (0)$ then $G_I(\mathbb Z) = \mathbb Z$, then $G_I(M)$ is f.g. $\mathbb Z$ module since Z is Noetherian, but if I take $M = (p) \supset (p^2) \supset (p^3) \cdots $ $IM_n = 0$ for all n, so the filtration is not stable.

Comment: Actually your last sentence (from the original question) seemed to point out that, *in general*, $G_{\mathcal F}(M)$ is a finitely generated $G_{\mathfrak a}(R)$-module when $\mathfrak a =\operatorname{Ann}(M)$, and this is why I've asked for some explanation.

Comment: @YACP yes, but I couldn't succeed in proving that, so I thought about this.

Comment: Okay. Now coming back to your example, I have to repeat the same question: why $G_I(M)$ is f.g. over $\mathbb Z$? (Take care that not all $\mathbb Z$-modules are f.g. despite the fact that $\mathbb Z$ is noetherian.)

Comment: @YACP, If Infinite sum of ideals is again an ideal, then $G_I(M)$ will be f.g. since $\mathbb Z$ is Noetherian, but I need to think for a proof or I should find a contradiction.

Comment: Nothing to think about: in your case $G_I(M)$ is definitely not finitely generated!

Comment: @YACP, yes, I tried to get another example but couldn't.